# SQL Server can't create sysname type colunmn

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to create a new table based on an existing table.
In the existing one, there are two columns that are `sysname` data type.

But when I'm trying to create the new one with `sysname`, SSMS shows

> Invalid data type

pop-up.
[image]
But this doesn't really make sense to me that if `sysname` is invalid, why it can be used in the old table?

My SQL Server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64)
SSMS version is 15.0.18390.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table designer is very limited and has a number of unresolved defects.

Most professionals choose to write T-SQL [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) statements instead.

You will have noticed `sysname` is not available in the drop-down list of type names.

This is probably because it is a synonym (for `nvarchar(128)`) rather than a base type.

If you want to leave feedback for Microsoft about this, you can do so at https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback